# String printed from the 2nd letter

Tags: c++, function, indexing

The purpose of this code is to validate a name and print each word with the 1st letter capitalize. I mean if the name inserted contains one of the char that are inside `Invalid_Name` it's not valide.

It works properly, but when I try to print that name, it starts from the 2nd letter. Just look at the code below(sorry for the size):

```
 void validate_charName()
{
    int i = 0;
    int check = 0;
    string Invalid_Name = "1234567890'!\"£$%&/()=?^*-+<>-.,_:;[]{}°@§";
    bool name_is_valide = true;

    // Validate the character's name
    while(name_is_valide)
    {
        bool invalid_name = false;
        name_is_valide = true;

        cout<< "\nWhat's the name of your character? " << endl;
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, char_name);

        for(int i = 0; i < char_name.length(); i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < Invalid_Name.length(); j++)
                {
                    if(char_name[i] == Invalid_Name[j])
                        invalid_name = true;
                }
        }
        if(invalid_name)
            cout<< "The name must contains only letters!" << endl;
        else
            name_is_valide = false;

    }


    while(char_name[i])
    {
        if(check == 0)
        {
            char_name[i] = toupper(char_name[i]);
            check = 1;
        }
        else if(isspace(char_name[i]))
            check = 0;
        i++;
    }
        sleepcp(1000);
        cout << "               ******Your character's name is " + char_name + "******                " << endl;
}
```

If I insert the name "edward kenway" it will print out `"Dward Kenway"`, even if I write  `i = 0;` before the loop.

Why?

*************EDIT*************

If i print the name in the right way since the first input, it works. Otherwise, it gives me that problem.

Comment: Why did you add `cin.ignore()`? If you remove it, first letter wouldn't be ignored.

Comment: I added it because getine() not worked without it.

Comment: @UnoaCaso then you are not using it correctly

Comment: Do you know why you sometimes need `cin.ignore()` before using `getline`? See https://stackoverflow.com/q/21567291/9254539. Don't write code that you don't understand. That's [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) and will get you nowhere. Instead, understand the problem.

Comment: If you've solved your problem, you can post an answer yourself.  Don't edit the solution into the question.

Comment: Why are you not simply using [std::basic_string::find_first_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of) to check for invalid characters?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Thanks, I don't knew that.

Comment: @David C. Rankin simply because i've never used that, in fact I'm going to learn about it rn.

Comment: Have a look at [get valid name example](https://paste.opensuse.org/38588731) which shows the use of `.find_first_of()` and `.find_first_not_of()`. (expires: Tue May 26 19:42:48 CDT 2020)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this just putting  "cin.sync()" before "getline()". Hope that can helps someone.